# Android Studio - AVD Manager is not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Studio 2.3.2 and
The **AVD Manager** (which should be under the tools menu is not visible).

Is there any way that i could make it available?

**Tools menu in Android Studio**

[image]

**Menus and Toolbars**

[image]

Comment: can you post the screenshot.?

Comment: I have posted some screenshots

Answer (score 15):

In the latest Android Studio(>= 3.6.2), it appears(mobile icon) at the top right side as displayed in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem that the AVD Manager didn't show up after I installed Android Studio 3.0.1. and I could not run my Ionic app in the emulator. After hours of researching this answer finally helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47727706/9386896

1. Start a blank project
2. Android Studio complained that certain SDK tools are missing and offers you to install them
3. After all tools where installed by Android Studio, I could finally create a virtual device via the AVD Manager.

I guess that may help Windows and Mac users.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ctrl+shift+A` to open the search and type **AVD Manager** and select it. From there you can manage all your virtual devices like Launch, edit config, delete Device etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in:

```
tool->Android->AVD Manager.
```

If you want to make the `AVD Manager` icon be visible, you can doing this:

Right click on the Toolbar and select the `Customize Menu and Toolbar..`,
Choose the Main Toolbar.

[image]

Then,you can see this:

[image]

Click on the `Restore Default`, then the `AVD Manager` will be visible. Hope this can help you. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have attached the screenshots kindly check it

Comment: I don't see Android as an option under Tool.

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure you have installed  Android emulator from sdk manager

[image]

> Then go to `tools -->android-->avd manager`

[image]

> if it doesn't work check `settings-->plugins-->android` support that
>   it(android support) is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Android plugin Enabled in your Studio:

File --> Settings-- > Type Plugin

Check Android and Restart Android Studio[image]