# Why AVD Manager options are not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Why i'm unable to see **Android Virtual Device (AVD)**

I'm facing problem to create `AVD` in `android studio`, the problem is i'm unable to see any of this option **Tools —> Android —> AVD Manager**

below screen shot  where i'm not finding  **Tools —> Android —> AVD Manager**

[image]

in the above screen shot you cannot find **Android --> AVD Manager**,Why it is not showing.

**Below is my installed packages:**

**1. SDK Manager**

[image]

**2. SDK Tools**

[image]

i'm following this link:http://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-create-android-virtual-device-avd-in-android-studio/

Comment: Does it now appear as "Device Manager"?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

I had installed Android studio and was not able to access the AVD Manager directly. I had to follow the steps as mentioned below:

1. Created a blank project using Android Studio
2. Once the Project is ready to use I tried open action using the shortcut  ctrl+shift+a option and searched for AVD Manager 
   [AVD Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe0Rn.png)
3. On double clicking the AVD Manager I got a few errors in console about the missing libararies along with the link to install the neccessary dependencies. On clicking the links which was displayed with the error message few packages which were needed were installed. Once all the required packages were installed the AVD Manager icon becomes active.

[image]

Comment: this didn't help me. AVD Manager runs fine. AS 3.1.4 can't see it, connect to it, get devices from it. Nothing.

Comment: After a fresh install it was missing. After 10 minutes of furious googling, the Tool menu suddenly tripled in size. I think it was loading all the tools in the background, slowly, with no indication of this happening.

Comment: I can confirm @RomanStarkov's experience.  It took about 11 minutes of doing nothing from the time that the IDE was freshly installed and up and running and seemingly ready to start running something with the emulator until the time that Tools > AVD Manager settings magically appeared.  Bad out-of-box experience.  It would be great if it said in the tools menu that "something components are still downloading..." or something.

Answer (score 65):

interesting, looks like all icon shifted to the right of toolbar.
please try open actions using shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + A` and than type AVD Manager, is avd manager options appear like this:

[image]

Comment: ya i'm able to find `AVD Manager` but the it is not opening why ? any idea, similar to your shown image

Comment: @EaB make sure to check/enable tools button from menu View->Tools Button

Comment: i got the `solution` by creating new  blank `android` `project` - thanks for your help

Comment: had to install SDK files

Comment: How's this can be helpful?

Answer (score 19):

The only thing that worked for me (with an existing project on a fresh install of macOS) was:

```
"File" > "Sync Project with Gradle Files"
```

This was odd to me since building the project succeeded with no errors or log messages, but I couldn’t run the project and there was nothing Android in the Tools menu.

I had already tried creating a new Android project and running that. It didn't help with my existing project.

Comment: This is the correct answer (and should become the accepted answer). It is possible to open Avd manager in different ways (using ctrl + shift + a), but if you want it to appear under Tools, you have to have to do a gradle sync.

Comment: This is the exact reason and solution! thanks a lot

Comment: This worked for me (I also had to comment out the line in my gradle file that locked the gradle version)

Answer (score 15):

Here is a screenshot of me fixing this. I've encountered it many times, and it's always due to this config-related jazz:

1. Click `Event Log` (bottom right)
2. Click `Configure` of the Android Framework detected notification
3. Done

[image]

If you do this and your icon still isn't lit up, then you probably need to set up the emulator still. I would recommend investigating the `SDK Manager` if so.

Comment: this didn't help at all.

Comment: You could accomplish similar by cloning the repo into a different folder and opening it in Android Studio. That should give you that `Configure` dialog. Maybe there is a different way to encounter this problem, but for me it's always been accidently or naively ignoring that "configure project" option.

Comment: Maybe you dont have a required SDK installed. Try the `Tools` menu and research from that heuristics assumption.

Comment: Pretty bizarre.The Tools... AVD Manager menu option was missing from my Android Studio; no idea why. Anyway, simply following this made it reappear! Nice :-)

Answer (score 8):

On linux I have same problem - its not listed in tools.

However there is a small icon:

[image]

Higlighted in yellow above in the top right corner of studio. It looks like a small phone with the android logo.

Answer (score 7):

I feel so damn silly. In my case, it turns out my Android Studio had two projects, one was for my React Native app root and the other for /android. If I closed the project and opened the /android project, I could access AVD Manager again.

[image: Example project list]

Answer (score 5):

Fixed by enabling Groovy plugin. Enabling it also enables the "SDK manager" option.

1. <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Type "Plugins"
3. Search for "Groovy"
4. Enable it and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

I found it from the icon. Please see the device icon.

[image]

Comment: I think they removed it from the Tools Menu. Why???

Answer (score 5):

For all of you having the new version of Android Studio, `AVD Manager` is now called `Device Manager`.

[image]

To create a new emulated device, go on **Tools -> Device Manager -> Create device**.

Comment: OMG, this is the very simple answer that needs more votes.
terminology is everything. no where else is this advised that the AVD Manager is now the Device Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Should be something to do with your Platform Settings. Try the below steps

1. Go to Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs
2. Select available SDK's as shown in screenshots
3. Re-start the Android Studio
4. Android will detect the framework in the right corner. Click on it
5. Then click ok as shown in second screenshot

[SDK's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2NDn.png)
[Setup Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KkDL.png)

Comment: It worked for me, but instead of restarting Android Studio I did "Apply" followed by "OK" combination.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

There could be a better way but this worked for me:

1) Open android studio, go to preferences by clicking on the top left 'Android Studio'

2) Search for 'avd' in the search bar. You'll see 'AVD Manager' in search results. It will be under 'Tools' folder.

3) Click on it and it will ask you to set up a short cut. Set it up. Say for example use 'V' as a shortcut.

4) Now open android studio and create a new project. After the project is created, press your shortcut that you had set. Like 'V' in our case. It will open the 'Virtual Devices Screen'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my React Native Project. Was not just that ADV Manager didn't show up on the menu but other tools where missing as well.

Everything was back to normal when I opened the project using **Import project** option instead of **Open an Existing Android Studio project**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After updating Android Studio to the latest version I finally found the AVD Manager:

1. (Update Android Studio)
2. Create a new project
3. Click on the device config dropdown:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me was pressing `ctrl+shift+a` search for `AVD` double click > install device. close and relaunch Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

It happens when there is no **runnable module** for Android App in your project. Creating new project definitely solves this.

You can check this using `Run > Edit Configurations > Adding Android App`. If there is not runnable Android App module then you can't see "AVD Manager" in the menu.

Comment: ths didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this implies some Android setup issue with the project. Go to the "Resource Manager" tab where you will be able to click on "Add Android Module" and click on import gradle files. If the import fails, you will get error messages that you can work with
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem on a Pixelbook. It ended up that I needed to enable: `Settings > Develop Android Apps > Enable ADB Debugging` in the Chromebook settings to get it working.

Based on that, it seems possible that if AVD isn't working on other computers it might be an issue with ADB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess AVD has been renamed to "Virtual Device Manager".

If you don't see it in the pop up menu do this:

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Type in "Virtual Device Manager"

Documentation:
[Create an AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find avd manager too.. I was using Ubuntu 20.04. Had Chipmunk version of Android Studio.

The thing that worked for me is

In `Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK`

There in the **SDK tools tab** (2nd tab in the main window) I enabled `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)`

That brought **avdmanager** in `Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`

Answer (score -1):

It Seems your AVD Manager is missing from root SDK directory please follow the Steps

1. Go to sdk\tools\lib\ and copy AVDManager.exe
2. Paste it to root of your sdk Directory.
   Now you have sdk\AVD Manager.exe

Now try to run it.