# How to open AVD manager in Android Studio 3.2 version on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't find AVD manager option in tools tab in android studio 3.2
There's no error message detected in event log.
[tool list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyMsS.jpg)

[installed sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6qHN.png)

But it works with command line tools
[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRFA.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173708/why-avd-manager-options-are-not-showing-in-android-studio/47727706

Comment: Thanks, it works, but is possible to make AVD manager to be visible in tools tab?