# I am unable to see in Android Studio, the AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-virtual-device

I am new to the android studio (3.6.3) and this is my first time creating an app using the kotlin language. But I could not access the AVD Manager to create an AVD to run the app. It is usually listed under the tools but this is what I see(I am on ChromeOS):
[Tools section in Android Studio on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tU2F.png)

I tried searching for AVD Manager by doing 'Ctr + Shift + A' but could not find it.
Also, I tried searching for this problem online but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to run option at the top:

[image]

See this link: [Why AVD Manager options are not showing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173708/why-avd-manager-options-are-not-showing-in-android-studio)

Comment: But how to add devices to that. Mine just shows no devices

Comment: @Shreeniket987 you have to download and create one

Comment: And where can I install it from? Thank you!

Comment: Click on Open AVD Manager in the image of my answer @Shreeniket987

Comment: I don't see that option on my device

Comment: I only see Run on multiple devices and trouble shoot device connections

Comment: I modified my answer @Shreeniket987