# Android Virtual Device does not appear anyone in my tools menu, how do I get it to appear?

Tags: android-studio, installation

I'm trying to run a simple reactive native tutorial, but I can't even get the AVD to load in Android studio.  I've attached a screenshot of my settings[image]

I'm 100% sure that I clicked on custom install and clicked on the AVD option.

Comment: This post explains how to find it [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228855/android-studio-avd-manager-is-not-visible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - AVD Manager is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228855/android-studio-avd-manager-is-not-visible)